# A Socratic look on the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

So a friend of mine and I were talking about the Residue Theorem and we were wondering if it is actually possible for a closed, rectifiable curve to contain a non-constant sequence of singularities and if in that case the Residue Theorem is applicable.

Let's add some symbolisms: Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:\Omega\setminus\{z_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function defined on $\Omega$ except of the **different** points $(z_n)$ which are $f$'s singularities. Let $\gamma$ be a closed, rectifiable, simple curve in $\Omega$, such that $z_n \not\in \hat{\gamma}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but all $z_n$ are *inside* $\gamma$, or if you'd like, $\chi(\gamma,z_n)=1$ .

Since the area inside $\gamma$ is a compact set, $(z_n)$ will have a converging sub-sequence, let's call it $(z_{n_k})$, with $z_{n_k}\to z_0$. There is no real interest if the singularities are removable from an index on, so let's suppose that they're all poles or essential singularities. The questions are the following:

1) Is it possible for the function $f$ to be holomorphic on the limit point $z_0$? Now if one says "but $z_0$ belongs to $\Omega$, that changes nothing, cause the question would become "can there be such a function $f$?"

2) Is it possible for the limit point $z_0$ to be in the *inside* of $\gamma$ and not on $\hat{\gamma}$?

3) If (1) is possible, would the Residue Theorem take the form of "Integral = Series of residues" ?

We know that $z_0$ can't be a singularity, since $f$ can't be defined on any ring $\Delta(z_0,0,r)=\{z: 0<|z-z_0|<r\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point $z_0$ is a singularity, since $f$ is not holomorphic on any neighborhood of $z_0$. It is a limit point of singularities, and as such, is not an isolated singularity. The classification of singularities as removable, poles or essential makes sense only for isolated singularities.

The standard example of such a situation is $f(z)=\Bigr(\sin\dfrac1z\Bigr)^{-1}$. The points $z_k=1/(k\,\pi)$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, $k\ne0$ are poles, and $0$ is a limit point of poles. There is no Laurent expansion around $0$, and hence no residue at $0$.

Comment: Apparently my terminology is a little mistaken; In the last sentence I'm stating that $z_0$ can't be a singularity, meaning that it can't be removable/pole/essential. Excuse me but I'm studying Complex Analysis in Greek and we use another term for singularities.

Comment: I can't seem to understand why in the general case, $f$ can't be holomorphic on a limit point of poles/essential singularities. Could you please explain?

Comment: To begin with, it is not even continuous. In every neighborhood of the limit point there is a pole, so that $f$ can't be holomorphic on any neighborhood of the limit point.

Comment: I thought the definition of continuity at point $z_0$ is $\forall\varepsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ such that if $w\in \Omega\cap D(z_0, \delta)$, then $f(w) \in D(f(z_0),\varepsilon)$. The poles are not in the domain $\Omega$ though;

Comment: Neither is the point $z_0$. What is $f(0)$ in the example in my answer? If $f$ were continuous at $z_0$ it would be bounded on a small disk centered a t $z_0$, but this is not so, since there are poles arbitrarily close to $z_0$.

Comment: Well, your example is not that helpful since we know that $0\not\in \Omega$ by start. But your other argument, that if $f$ was continuous on $z_0$ then it would be bounded around it, convinces me. Thanks for your time and I'm sorry if i bored you with all those comments!